# Solve equation $8\cos x - 6\sin x = 5$ where $0 \le x \le 360$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve equation $8\cos x - 6\sin x = 5$ where $0 \le x \le 360$.

I am not asked to use any form, so I am going to use $k\cos(x-\alpha)$.

$8\cos x - 6\sin x = k\cos(x-\alpha)$

$$=k(\cos x\cos\alpha + \sin x\sin\alpha)$$
$$=k\cos\alpha\cos x + k\sin\alpha\sin x$$

equating coefficients:

$k\cos\alpha = 8$

$k\sin\alpha = 6$, or is it $k\sin\alpha = -6$? I find this really confusing

$k = \sqrt{8^2 + 6^2} = 10$

$\alpha$ is in the 1st quadrant where both sin and cos are positive.

$\alpha = \arctan\frac{6}8 = 36.8^{\circ}$

$\therefore10\cos(x - 36.8) = 5$

I have a maximum and minimum value of 10

From here I do not know how to finish solving for x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $k\sin\alpha = 6$, or is it $k\sin\alpha = -6$?

It is the latter.

So, having $\tan\alpha=-6/8=-3/4$ gives $\alpha=\arctan(-3/4)\approx -36.9^\circ$.

Hence, for $n\in\mathbb Z$,
$$\begin{align}10\cos(x-(-36.9^\circ))=5&\Rightarrow \cos(x+36.9^\circ)=1/2\\&\Rightarrow x+36.9^\circ=\pm 60^\circ+360^\circ n\\&\Rightarrow x=-36.9^\circ\pm 60^\circ+360^\circ n\\&\Rightarrow x=23.1^\circ,\quad 263.1^\circ\end{align}$$
since $0^\circ\le x\le 360^\circ$.

Comment: I am baffled by the equating coefficients, if I was expressing $4\cos x  - 3\sin x$ in the form $k\sin(x-\alpha)$ then $k\cos\alpha = -3$ and $k\sin\alpha = -4$ which seems contradictory to $k\sin\alpha = -6$ in this example

Comment: @dagda1: $k\cos\alpha=-3$ and $k\sin\alpha=-4$ are correct. In our example, we have $\color{red}{8}\cos x\color{green}{-6}\sin x=k\cos(x-\alpha)=k(\cos x\cos\alpha+\sin x\sin\alpha)=\color{red}{k\cos\alpha}\cos x\color{green}{+k\sin\alpha}\sin x$, and so $\color{green}{-6=+k\sin\alpha}$. I hope this helps.

Comment: so $x = 60 + -36.9$ or $x = 360 - 60 + -36.9$ I don't understand where these values are coming from.  it would be great if you have a link or something that explains this or even better, expand on your answer

Comment: @dagda1: Do you mean how $\cos\theta=1/2$ leads $\theta=\pm 60^\circ+360^\circ n$ where $n\in\mathbb Z$, or else?

Comment: I understand where $60^{\circ}$ comes from and I get why $x = 60 - 36.9$ but I don't understand the $x = 360 - 60 - 36.9$, I had to reverse engineer it from your answer or indeed why 60 is plus or minus

Comment: @dagda1: OK, let me explain. $x=-36.9\pm 60+360n$ means that $x=-36.9+60+360n$ or $x=-36.9-60+360n$. For the former, we have to take $n=0$ because of $0\le x\le 360$. For the latter, we have to take $n=1$ for the same reason. I hope this helps.

Comment: this is a big help

Comment: I can see where 0 comes form by why does 360 = 1 for n and sorry for the questions but this is very good for me

Comment: @dagda1: If we solve $0\le -36.9-60+360n\le 360$, then we have $0.3\approx 96.9/360\le n\le 456.9/360\approx 1.3$, from which we have $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The general method of solving $A\cos x+B\sin x=C$ when $A^2+B^2\ne 0$ is to take any $y$ such that $$(1)\quad A/\sqrt {A^2+B^2}=\cos y\;\land \;B/\sqrt {A^2+B^2}=\sin y.$$  $$\text {Then } C/\sqrt {A^2+B^2}=\cos y \cos x+\sin y \sin x =\cos (x-y).$$ So let  $x=y+z$ for any $z$ such that $\cos z=C/\sqrt {A^2+B^2}.$

If we are strictly in the real numbers we require $|C/\sqrt {A^2+B^2}|\leq 1......$ Let $y_0$ satisfy (1) with $y_0\in [0,\pi].$  Let $z_0=\cos^{-1}(C/\sqrt {A^2+B^2})\in [0,\pi].$ Then $x=2\pi n \pm (y_0+z_0)$ for some (any) integer $n.$

Answer (score 0):

So, $\cos(x-\alpha)=\dfrac5{10}=\cos60^\circ$

$\implies x-\alpha=360^\circ n\pm60^\circ$ where $n$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

converting the given equation into $$\tan(x/2)$$ we get
$$8\,{\frac {1- \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{1+ \left( 
\tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}-12\,{\frac {\tan \left( x/2
 \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( x/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}-5
=0$$
setting $$\tan(x/2)=t$$ you have to solve this equation
$$-{\frac {13\,{t}^{2}+12\,t-3}{{t}^{2}+1}}=0$$ for $$t$$